# Change <td> element value on change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table like this:

```
Column 1 | Column 2
-------------------
Textbox1 | Text1
Textbox2 | Text2
```

I want to change the `Textbox1` value and when the cursor move out it will run the `change` events to replace the `Text1` value to `Success`.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Demo - Change Value</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#example table tbody tr td input').change(function() {
                    var rowEdit = $($(this).parents('tr').html());

                    rowEdit.closest('.sub').html('Success');
<!--                    $('.sub').html('Change');-->
                })
            })
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="example">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <th>Column 1</th>
                    <th>Column 2</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="text" /></td>
                        <td class="sub">123</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="text" /></td>
                        <td class="sub">456</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The problem is, the value didn't change after I call the `rowEdit.closest('.sub').html('success');` but it will change the `Text1` and `Text2` if I use `$('.sub').html('Change');`.

**My goal is to change the text inside the Column 2 when I change the value of `input` of the column 1 with same row. How can I achieve that?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example table tbody tr td input').change(function() {
    var rowEdit = $(this).parents('tr');
    rowEdit.children('.sub').html('Success');
  })
})
```

Since you fetched the parent tr element, children() should do the trick.

Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RTDSh/)

Comment: No need to re-wrap `rowEdit` as a jQuery Object. You already refer to it in the initial variable instantiation.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand exactly what you are trying to do, but check this out

[JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7u9DU/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this.... **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/RTDSh/1/)**

```
$('#example input').change(function() {
   $(this).closest('tr').find('td.sub').html('Success');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Added changes to JS Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/abhisheks/ZPLdu/2

Please let me know, if there is any other change.